# function Values and Local Variables injavascript

Tags: javascript

```
var a = null;
function b() {return "B";}
(a || b)();
```

when i `alert((a || b)());`.it shows B. why? the return of `a || b` is true or false. why the above return B.

2:Local Variables

```
function power(base, exponent) {
var result = 1;
for (var count = 0; count < exponent; count++)
result *= base;
return result;
}
power(2, 10);
```

a book says

> if power were to call itself, that
>   call would cause a new, distinct
>   result variable to be created and used
>   by the inner call and would leave the
>   variable in the outer call untouched.

i can't follow it well, expect someone can explain it to me. many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

The return value of `||` is not boolean.

It is the first argument if it is truthy or the second argument if it is not.

So `a || b` is equivalent to `a ? a : b` and `a && b` is equivalent to `a ? b : a`.

2.

When power is called, a new frame is pushed onto the call stack to hold the paramaters and local variables like other languages.  But JavaScript is a bit different from many languages in that when a function call results in a new function instance being created, the new function instance holds a reference to the stack frames on the stack when it is created.  Since these stack frames hold locals, there is a different place in memory for functions created by different calls to the same function.

For example, in

```
function makeCounter() {
  var counter = 0;
  return function () { return counter++; };
}

var c1 = makeCounter();
var c2 = makeCounter();
c1(); c1(); c1();
c2(); c2();
alert(c1() + ", " + c2());  // -> 3, 2
alert(c1() + ", " + c2());  // -> 4, 3
```

`makeCounter` is first called to initialize `c1`.  This creates a stack frame like `{ counter: 0 }` which the first counter function points to.
The second call to `makeCounter` used to initialize `c2` creates a different stack frame.

So the code above is equivalent to

```
var c1SFrame = { counter: 0 };
var c2SFrame = { counter: 0 };
c1SFrame.counter++; c1SFrame.counter++; c1SFrame.counter++;
c2SFrame.counter++; c2SFrame.counter++; c2SFrame.counter++;
alert(c1SFrame++ + ", " + c2SFrame++);
alert(c1SFrame++ + ", " + c2SFrame++);
```

which should make it obvious why it alerts what it does.

Comment: If x=10 and y= 5 then (x=10) || (y=10) return is true .this example is like the above example.  why the above  return value is  not boolean.

Comment: @zhuanzhou, no, the result of `(x=10) || (y=10)` is `10` since the result of both assignments is `10`.  If you meant to say, `(x == 10) || (y == 10)` then that would be true because the result of `x == 10` is `true` and `true ? true : false` is `true`.

Comment: i found the example form this.http://bton.com/tb16/jsref/operator.html (Comparison and Logical Operators part)so the examplt is wrong? am i right? thank you.

Comment: to the question 2, could you make me a simple example? many thanks.

Comment: @zhuanzhou, yes.  The examples at that website are hopelessly muddled.  Adding an example for point 2.